# print empty cell in Latex

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have an array stored in csv file from Python program as :

W = [ 1,
          2,
          ,
          4,
           ,
          5]

I want to print the array in Latex as :

```
W
1
2

4

5
```

I have tried with below code:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=tab ]{w.csv}{\table}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[ precision= 6,
begin table=\begin{longtable},
    end table=\end{longtable},
display columns/0/.style={column name=$x_n$},
]{\table}
```

but It does not print the empty fields. Rather it prints as:

```
W
1
2
4
5
```

How can I print the data from the csv file with empty spaces?

Comment: take a look at `empty cells with` in `pgfplotstable` manual

Comment: Two tabs might not be recognized as separate ones as the parser starts looking at the next nontab character after the first (if I'm not mistaken). Try using other separators as comma (which is what csv is ;) )

Comment: @Ignasi I'm reviewing old unanswered questions, would you like to post an answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I'm sorry, but after reviewing the question and my comment I cannot provide an answer. There's no information about the csv format and no relation between the code used and the result.